# t1.start() TypeError: start() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python

```
from time import sleep         
from threading import *        
                               
class Hello(Thread):           
        def run(self):         
            for i in range(5): 
                print("working 
                sleep(1)       
                               
class Hi(Thread):              
    def run(self):             
        for i in range(5):     
            print("Going GOOd")
            sleep(1)           
                               
                               
t1 = Hello                     
t2 = Hi                        
                               
t1.start()                     
t2.start()                     
                               
t1.join()                      
t2.join()                      
                               
print("Have a Good Day ahead")
```

Comment: You missed `()` when you instantiate your classes: `t1 = Hello()` `t2 = Hi()`

Comment: Also try not to use `import *`. Here it is better if you use `from threading import Thread` (although it is not the cause of your problem).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to instantiate the subclasses of `Thread`, here you go:

```
class Hello(Thread):
    def run(self):
        for i in range(5): 
            print("working")
            sleep(1)

class Hi(Thread):
    def run(self):
        for i in range(5):
            print("Going GOOd")
            sleep(1)

t1 = Hello()
t2 = Hi()

t1.start()
t2.start()

t1.join()
t2.join()

print("Have a Good Day ahead")
```